# Cutting mesh textures

Tags: mesh, texturing, uv

I have a problem with the textures or actually with a very weird problem.
I have a big terrain which has over 100 000 vertices. And I have textured the whole terrain to the same texture file.(UV unwrapping)
Now I cutted my terrain to 64 pieces with the slicer tool(external). For performance issues I want to also cut the texture file. So I want to make texture file for every piece also.

So, I have 64 small part of the big terrain and one big texture atlas, where is all textures of the all parts.

Is there any tool, addon or software which could read the texture coordinates of parts and pick it's textures from texture atlas and make new texture file where is only the textures of the that part?
Or is there easy way to do it manually? Or does blender have tehcnique for my problem?

Thanks for answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know any way of doing this automatically, but you can do it manually.  I believe what you want to do is *export your UV layout*.  You can do this in the UV editor under *UVs > Export UV layout*.

[image]

It will export a .png file with transparency which you can then use as an overlay in a program like Photoshop or Gimp to manually cut up your existing UV atlas.

[image]